# Wildcards in vera++

Tags: c++, static-analysis, vera++

I feel really really dumb but how do I use wildcards with vera++?
I would think I could do:

```
vera++ --root "C:\Program Files (x86)\vera++\lib\vera++" -R L001 *.cpp
```

But I get:

```
error: cannot open source file *.cpp
while executing
"GetAllLines $f"
...
```

Thanks,
Daniel Dekkers

Comment: Expanding wildcards is a shell feature not one of the called program.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - In Windows, wildcard expansion is the responsibility of the called program.  See, e.g., [here](http://superuser.com/q/460598/4160).

Comment: @JoshKelley I was afraid so. Then the OP should try to run the program in e.g. MinGw shell.

Comment: Or use a Makefile or something similar.

Comment: Ok, so something like
`for %%f in (*.cpp) do (
vera++ --root "C:\Program Files (x86)\vera++\lib\vera++" %%~nf.cpp -R L001
)` in a windows batch file.

Comment: @DanielDekkers:  If you have come up with a working solution, you should post it as an answer.  You can even select it as "the" answer, if you'd like.  It might help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

- It would appear that Vera++ does not support this.  (On Windows, handling wildcards is the responsibility of individual programs; on other platforms, it's handled by the shell. If Vera++ is primarily developed by non-Windows users, that may explain the oversight.)
- [You're not the first person to run into this.](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/issue/62/scan-multiple-files-eg-cpp)
- There are several workarounds: pass `-` as a filename and pipe in a list of files on stdin, or use a Makefile or similar script or tool runner, or use [PowerShell or a for loop](https://superuser.com/q/460598/4160), or use another shell (like MinGW or Cygwin).